# Find limit if it exists and explain why if it does not: $\lim_{x\to 0} \cos(1/x) e^x$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, taylor-expansion

I started with the Taylor expansions of $\cos(1/x)$ and $e^x$

i.e

$\cos(1/x) : [ 1 - \frac{1}{2x^2} +  o(\frac{1}{x^4}) ]$

and

$e^x : ( 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2} + o(x^3) )$

I realise $e^x$ goes to $1$ as $x \to 0$ so can we ignore the $e^x$ term and focus only on the $\cos(1/x)$ term? How would you proceed from there on?

Answer (score 4):

The limits along the sequences $(\frac  1 {\frac {\pi } 2+2n \pi})$ and $(\frac  1 {2n \pi})$ are $0$ and $1$ respectively. Hence the limit does not exist.

[$\cos (\frac {\pi } 2+2n \pi)=0$ for all $n$, $\cos ( 2n \pi)=1$ for all $n$ and $e^{x}$ part can be ignored as you have already observed. For existence of the limit it is necessary that limit along all sequences converging to $)$ are the same].

Comment: where is the work? I havent downvoted but it seems the reason is because of the low quality answer for a high rep user...

Comment: @ILoveMath Posting answers that can be copied and pasted into home work is immoral.

Comment: +1 its a nice answer. I dont know about the immorality part. However, do you think all questions are homework questions? I think you have a false premise there

Answer (score 2):

In the Limit Toolbox we have: If $\lim_{x\to a}U(x)=P\in \Bbb R$ and $\lim_{x\to a}V(x)=Q\in \Bbb R$ then $\lim_{x\to a}U(x)V(x)=PQ.$

With $a=0,$ let $U(x)=e^x\cos (1/x)$ for $x\ne 0$ and let $V(x)=e^{-x}.$ We have $\lim_{x\to a}V(x)=1=Q\in \Bbb R.$

IF $\lim_{x\to a}U(x)=P\in \Bbb R$ THEN $\lim_{x\to 0}\cos (1/x)=\lim_{x\to a}U(x)V(x)=PQ\in \Bbb R.$

Does $\cos (1/x)$ have a limit as $x\to 0?$